# Spring boot app with cosmos managed identity

Tags: spring-boot, azure, kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb

I am using spring boot application which is deployed to aks.

The application connects Azure cosmos db.
The connection details are provided in application.yml

I am trying to get rid of connection url and introduce cosmos db managed identity system/user.

Any idea or link to help out how to connect spring boot with cosmos managed identity

Comment: is this for SQL API?

Comment: Welcome! Please be mindful of tags: you used `[cosmos]` which has nothing to do with Cosmos DB (and the description explicitly mentions this as well, and to use `[azure-cosmosdb]`) - I've fixed this, accordingly.

Comment: Aside from tagging: Please edit to include details about what you've done, errors, issues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

•   Azure cosmos DB supports managed identity access at system level as well as user-based level. Thus, you can configure managed identity access to azure cosmos DB through a spring boot application hosted in azure AKS cluster by configuring the managed identity for the configured spring boot app as below: -

```
Go to your cosmos DB account  Settings  Identity  System assigned, or User assigned  Save. You can also set azure active directory-based role assignments to the cosmos DB account as well.
```

•   If you access your hosted spring boot app in AKS and retrieve the service principal ID for assigning a system managed identity through role assignment to azure cosmos DB for managed identity access, you can run use the following command for assigning the service principal to a parameter, then assign a response, content and ARMToken parameter and then use the access token retrieved earlier to get the access keys to access the cosmos DB.

Note : - Below is a sample command to assign a service principal to a parameter

```
 ‘ $spID = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myRG -Name 
  myVM).identity.principalid
  New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spID -RoleDefinitionName 
  "Cosmos DB Account Reader Role" -Scope 
  "/subscriptions/<mySubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/
  <myResourceGroup>/providers/
   Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/<COSMOS DB ACCOUNT 
   NAME>" '
```

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-cosmos-db

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication

Comment: Please note that documentation-request questions are off-topic. And the OP still has not updated their question with specific issues, following my comments requesting more details several days ago. There's no need to post such answers, since there is no detailed question to answer.